# How to get distinct values of sql table column in datagrid column as dropdown?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datasource

I want to create a DataGridView in Windows form C# .net

This DataGridView will have one column as combo box

For Example:
Consider below SQL Table

```
ID      Name    Country
101     Jack    USA
102     Jill    France
103     Rose    USA
104     John    USA
```

Now I want to show to table data in datagridview, which I am able to do by adding this table in DataSource property.
Also I want to convert Country column into combo box , which is also I am able to do using edit columns and then changing type to DataGridViewColumnComboBox  and adding DataSourceaas this table and  DataMember as Country column.

**But the issue is, Country Combobox column of DataGridView is now showing List of all values in Country column (i.e. USA,France,USA,USA)  . But I want it to show just distinct values (i.e. USA,France)**

Note: This is just an example. Need to implement this kind of functionality in actual project

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to populate the ComboBox?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can get unique values.

You can use [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) to remove duplicate entries.

Assuming you have the DataTable in your question then you could do something like this:

```
var dt = ... // get your data
var countries = dt.AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(r => new { Country = r.Field<string>("Country") })
                  .Select(g => g.First())
                  .CopyToDataTable();
```

which returns a DataTable with a `Country` column containing only distinct entries.  You will be able to bind the ComboBox DataSource to this DataTable.

---

Another option is [Distinct()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8).

```
var countries = dt.AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(r => r.Field<string>("Country"))
                  .Distinct()
                  .ToList();
```

I find GroupBy easier to use when selecting more than a single field.  The reason is that with Distinct() you may need to create your own custom EqualityComparer.

To use these methods please include a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`.

Comment: There is a `Distinct` method as well. For example: `var list = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Country")).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: @RezaAghaei I updated my answer to include your suggestion.  When selecting multiple fields I usually prefer GroupBy over Distinct.